# Unity using C# to read sqlite data in chinese

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Im trying to read a data in sqlite.It is a string in chinese.I got a garbled,messy encode,I searched that sqlite is using utf-8 to encode.And C# is utf-16?not sure.But I have no idea how to address this problem.
I have tried PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-16"in sqlite but it makes no sense.
The data in sqlite displayed correctly.

Comment: While Unicode cut down on the Encoding/Codepage issues massively, even it failed at completely elliminating them. Here is an article on the mater: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: thanks pretty much,im reading it.Hope it will help.